# Converting C# regex to JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

In C# I am using this regex:

```
 string pattern = @"(?<!"")\:([^\:]*)\:";
```

and it is working fine but when I try to use it in JavaScript it gives Syntax error:

```
var pattern = /(?<!"")\:([^\:]*)\:/g;
```

Can you let me know the issue with that regex with JavaScript?

Comment: javascript does not support lookbehinds.. `?<!...)`

Comment: Okay. Can you suggest the regex I should use then?

Comment: @raj: what do you want to do with this regex? Matching? replacing?...

Comment: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question, but you can verify the results of a javascript regex using a regex tester, such as this one: https://regex101.com/#javascript

Comment: Can you explain what you want the expression to find and give an example of sample inputs/matches?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript do not support Zero-width negative lookbehind assertion.